# Pytorch RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (120000) must match the size of tensor b (2) at non-singleton dimension 2

Tags: python, pytorch

I use code from here to train a model to predict the function of DNA:

The code with bug as follow.

```
class upd_GELU(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(upd_GELU, self).__init__()
        self.constant_param = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor([1,702]))
        self.sig = nn.Sigmoid()
        
    def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
        print(self.constant_param.shape)
        print(input.shape)
        outval = torch.mul(self.sig(torch.mul(self.constant_param, input)), input)
        return outval
```

error message as follow:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [73], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 net = BasenjiModel()
----> 2 summary(net, input_size = [(4, 120000)], batch_size = BATCH_SIZE, device = "cpu")
      4 def opt_rule(epoch):
      5     if epoch >= 34:

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchsummary/torchsummary.py:72, in summary(model, input_size, batch_size, device)
     68 model.apply(register_hook)
     70 # make a forward pass
     71 # print(x.shape)
---> 72 model(*x)
     74 # remove these hooks
     75 for h in hooks:

...(This part is omitted)

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py:1128, in Module._call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1125     bw_hook = hooks.BackwardHook(self, full_backward_hooks)
   1126     input = bw_hook.setup_input_hook(input)
-> 1128 result = forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1129 if _global_forward_hooks or self._forward_hooks:
   1130     for hook in (*_global_forward_hooks.values(), *self._forward_hooks.values()):

Input In [64], in upd_GELU.forward(self, input)
      8 print(self.constant_param.shape)
      9 print(input.shape)
---> 10 outval = torch.mul(self.sig(*torch.mul(input, self.constant_param)*), input)
     11 return outval

RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (120000) must match the size of tensor b (2) at non-singleton dimension 2
```

The size of these two tensor:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4WlF.png)

How can I fix it? Thanks a lot.

Why wasn't it broadcast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the function `torch.mul` tensors should be with the same number of dimensions. However in your case the multiplied tensors are not with the same dimension. Same as in this example:

```
import torch
a = torch.randn(2)
b = torch.randn(2,4,120000)
print("shape of a:" + str(a.shape))
print("shape of b:" + str(b.shape))
result = torch.mul(a,b)
```

Output:

```
shape of a:torch.Size([2])
shape of b:torch.Size([2, 4, 120000])    
The size of tensor a (2) must match the size of tensor b (120000) at non- 
singleton dimension 2
```

You should add dimensions to the first tensor in the example case is a, as follow:

```
import torch
a = torch.randn(2).unsqueeze(1).unsqueeze(2)
b = torch.randn(2,4,120000)
print("shape of a:" + str(a.shape))
print("shape of b:" + str(b.shape))
result = torch.mul(a,b)
print("shape of result:"+str(result.shape))
```

Output:

```
shape of a:torch.Size([2, 1, 1])
shape of b:torch.Size([2, 4, 120000])
shape of result:torch.Size([2, 4, 120000])
```

In you example, this modification should solve the problem:

```
class upd_GELU(nn.Module):
def __init__(self):
    super(upd_GELU, self).__init__()
    self.constant_param = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor([1,702]))
    self.sig = nn.Sigmoid()
    
def forward(self, input: Tensor) -> Tensor:
    self.constant_param = self.constant_param.unsqueeze(1).unsqueeze(2)
    outval = torch.mul(self.sig(torch.mul(self.constant_param, input)), input)
    return outval
```